# Array of 12 elements- find count- practice

Tags: c++, arrays

Could you guys please walk and help me with this practice question?
I'm unable to figure out how the answer is 5.

```
int arr[12] = { 1,3,5,0,7,2,0,4,4,0,8,8 };
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<11; i++) {
    if (arr[i] = arr[i + 1])
        count++;
    else
        count--;
}
cout << count << endl;
```

Comment: Remember `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you have :

```
if (arr[i] = arr[i + 1])
```

which is the `=`, not `==`. It is assigning not checking for equality. So in the example:

```
if (a = 3) {
```

You will assign `a` to `3` and check if `3` is `true`, which it is. This leads to an easy look at why the answer is 5:

```
arr=>  { 1,3,5,0,7,2,0,4,4,0,8,8 };
count=>    1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5
```

And if you are interested, look at the array after you have completed. It will look like this:

```
{3,5,0,7,2,0,4,4,0,8,8,8} // Everything has been moved down 1 (except for the final member)
```

[See a live example of this here](https://ideone.com/SAvqrR).